# How to call an async function in textinput?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, react-lifecycle-hooks

How to call an async function with in textinput?

```
getTxt = async () => {

    filetxt = 'abc';
    currentFileName = this.props.navigation.getParam("currentFileName");
    console.log(currentFileName);

    try {

        filetxt = FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(`${FileSystem.documentDirectory}${currentFileName}.txt`, { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingTypes.UTF8 });

        console.log(filetxt);

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    return filetxt;
}

render() {

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <TextInput
                multiline = {true}
                style={{ margin : 10 }}
            >{ await this.getTxt() }
            </TextInput>
            <Button onPress = { this.FunctionToOpenFirstActivity } title = 'Save'/>
        </View>
    );
}
```

There is an error "await is a reserved words", anyknow knows?

Comment: That's exactly what the state is for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-arrange the code to get desired result. You can't use await in render() which is not async function. If you call async function getTxt without await, it will return a promise. So the filetext will be empty at the time of rendering. You need to make use of state to automatically re-render when value changes.

```
// Initialise filetext with state
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      filetext: ""
    };
  }
// Make componentWillMount async and invoke getTxt with await
async componentWillMount() {
 let text = await this.getTxt();
 this.setState({ filetext: text });
}

//Access filetext from the state so that it will automatically re-render when value changes

render() {

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <TextInput
                multiline = {true}
                style={{ margin : 10 }}
            >{ this.state.filetext }
            </TextInput>
            <Button onPress = { this.FunctionToOpenFirstActivity } title = 'Save'/>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function without await keyword

```
this.getTxt()
```

Your code will like:

```
getTxt = async () => {

    filetxt = 'abc';
    currentFileName = this.props.navigation.getParam("currentFileName");
    console.log(currentFileName);

    try {

        filetxt = FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(`${FileSystem.documentDirectory}${currentFileName}.txt`, { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingTypes.UTF8 });

        console.log(filetxt);

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    return filetxt;
}

render() {

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <TextInput
                multiline = {true}
                style={{ margin : 10 }}
            >{ this.getTxt() }
            </TextInput>
            <Button onPress = { this.FunctionToOpenFirstActivity } title = 'Save'/>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Render is not a async function , so you can not use await in render, you can do it in componentWillMount and keep it in a state the put that state in render method